# A great desire for some!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Obsessive and greedy,
>   A great desire for some,
>   Won through hard work,
>   But can impede on freedom.
>
> A legend of ancient times,
>   For the foundations laid he,
>   A marker for our thinking,
>   The guide for you and me.
>
> Reach to edge of space,
>   Beauty and life to meet,
>   Exceptional to perceivers,
>   Natural art is such a feat!
>
> Old British comedy R.I.P,
>   For one will annoy later,
>   The surname gives the net,
>   Now all is stored as data.
>
> Its seems too many are now,
>   Some from dance or songs,
>   The internet produces a lot,
>   For many the heart longs.
>
> To guide from the shadows,
>   It’s that which most have sought,
>   Imagine that it were a job,
>   For many, they have bought.
>
> Some people have many friends,
>   Some just hang out as a crew,
>   Many aspire that become them,
>   Sometimes that’s me and you.
>
> Suddenly a change of plans,
>   Will be decided by the chief,
>   To turn around for best results,
>   That will be your belief.
>
> Often shown as good to us,
>   Also powerful and buff,
>   Most will stay unnoticed,
>   For doing the simple stuff.
>
> Obsessive they will appear to be,
>   For loving something dearly,
>   It could be caused by anything,
>   From race cars to pepperoni!
>
> Stories are often told to us,
>   So ancient from across the seas,
>   They tell of mighty warriors,
>   That never asked for fees.
>
> The next three are grouped as one,
>   Only differing by their ranking,
>   To uphold us from the evil ones,
>   They’re often just out walking.
>
> Insuring that your transport’s comfy,
>   They will make your trip better,
>   It is their job, and they get no praise,
>   Not even a thank-you letter.
>
> To use again for faster results,
>   Taking others working is the key,
>   Some may view as an evil act,
>   And expose you for all to see.
>
> They wish to gain power over you,
>   Most do through promise not fear,
>   They will change the way you live,
>   In addition to the rest of the area.
>
> The latter usually relies on this,
>   The organise all that they meet,
>   Through working with every man,
>   To get only one man his seat.

***Now at the end of this rhyme,

They all have a common link,

Secrets revealed one by one,

So use your brain and think!***

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer

> Money?

Obsessive and greedy,
A great desire for some,
Won through hard work,
But can impede on freedom.

> You need to work to make money, but it can take up a lot of your time.

A legend of ancient times,
For the foundations laid he,
A marker for our thinking,
The guide for you and me.

> A treasure hunt, perhaps?

Reach to edge of space,
Beauty and life to meet,
Exceptional to perceives,
Natural art is such a feat!

> ...you need to pay to go to space?

Old British comedy R.I.P,
For one will annoy later,
The surname gives the net,
Now all is stored as data.

> Bitcoins?

It seems too many are now,
Some from dance or songs,
The internet produces a lot,
For many the heart longs.

> You can get money from the Internet, as well as making music and dancing etc.

To guide from the shadows,
It’s that which most have sought,
Imagine that it were a job,
For many, they have bought.

> It's behind a lot of the things that you do?

Some people have many friends,
Some just hang out as a crew,
Many aspire that become them,
Sometimes that’s me and you.

No idea here.

Suddenly a change of plans,
Will be decided by the chief,
To turn around for best results,
That will be your belief.

> Hmm. You've just gotten fired?

Often shown as good to us,
Also powerful and buff,
Most will stay unnoticed,
For doing the simple stuff.

> You don't notice the money behind a lot of things?

Obsessive they will appear to be,
For loving something dearly,
It could be caused by anything,
From race cars to pepperoni!

> Race cars and pepperoni both cost money.

Stories are often told to us,
So ancient from across the seas,
They tell of mighty warriors,
That never asked for fees.

> Books cost money? **shrug**

The next three are grouped as one,
Only differing by their ranking,
To uphold us from the evil ones,
They’re often just out walking.

Insuring that your transport’s comfy,
They will make your trip better,
It is their job, and they get no praise,
Not even a thank-you letter.

> You pay for stuff on e.g an airplane.

To use again for faster results,
Taking others working is the key,
Some may view as an evil act,
And expose you for all to see.

> You pay for people to do work.

They wish to gain power over you,
Most do through promise not fear,
They will change the way you live,
In addition to the rest of the area.

The later usually relies on this,
The organise all that they meet,
Through working with every man,
To get only one man his seat.

Comment: Sorry this isn't correct. Its the right idea but the puzzle is solved clue by clue (see the bold paragraph)

Comment: The problem with making it so long is that it becomes tedious to type out a solution to every single line. By 'the right idea' do you mean that my final answer is correct?

Comment: There is a solution to each stanza, this isn't the correct final answer but it is somewhat related.

Comment: You may not need answers to all of them to see the pattern

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess it would be a

> HERO of a classic novel/ an epic / movie

and the explanation goes like this

Obsessive and greedy,
A great desire for some,
Won through hard work,
But can impede on freedom.

> A position at the top is a type of obsessive greediness for some and it comes at the cost of one's freedom !

A legend of ancient times,
For the foundations laid he,
A marker for our thinking,
The guide for you and me.

> Greek philosophers / political thought-leaders(Aristotle / Plato) have already communicated this and made prominent work in these which till today act as guide to students

Reach to edge of space,
Beauty and life to meet,
Exceptional to perceivers,
Natural art is such a feat!

> Hero / heroines are supposed to perform as exceptional artistes !!

Old British comedy R.I.P,
For one will annoy later,
The surname gives the net,
Now all is stored as data.

> Charlie Chaplin is being referred...

Its seems too many are now,
Some from dance or songs,
The internet produces a lot,
For many the heart longs.

> Too many cine heroes are now (compared to earlier times, where only few are there !)

To guide from the shadows,
It’s that which most have sought,
Imagine that it were a job,
For many, they have bought.

> Being a hero/heroine is not a JOB but in few cases it was a bought thing !

Some people have many friends,
Some just hang out as a crew,
Many aspire that become them,
Sometimes that’s me and you.

> Sometimes, heros / heroines are made from common public (means not necessarily hereditary / hierarchical)

Suddenly a change of plans,
Will be decided by the chief,
To turn around for best results,
That will be your belief.

> God willing,  you may become a super-star or altogether to nowhere

Often shown as good to us,
Also powerful and buff,
Most will stay unnoticed,
For doing the simple stuff.

> Generally hero/heroines are shown as good ones, powerful with little comedy added to it and no one notices for their casual roles !

Obsessive they will appear to be,
For loving something dearly,
It could be caused by anything,
From race cars to pepperoni!

> Generally hero/heroines are reported to be having luxurious life styles !

Stories are often told to us,
So ancient from across the seas,
They tell of mighty warriors,
That never asked for fees.

> Ancient legends of hero/heroines involved wars/battles ... !

The next three are grouped as one,
Only differing by their ranking,
To uphold us from the evil ones,
They’re often just out walking.

> To be provided (perhaps Director, Producer and Villain)

Insuring that your transport’s comfy,
They will make your trip better,
It is their job, and they get no praise,
Not even a thank-you letter.

> To be provided ...

To use again for faster results,
Taking others working is the key,
Some may view as an evil act,
And expose you for all to see.

> A case of remaking already made films / restoration / computerization of the old films / piracy justifies these lines.

They wish to gain power over you,
Most do through promise not fear,
They will change the way you live,
In addition to the rest of the area.

> Practical cases of heroic acts inspiring common man and done both good and bad in the past (and happens in the present too !).

The later usually relies on this,
The organise all that they meet,
Through working with every man,
To get only one man his seat.

> To warn the common man that he/she should realise and live up to himself/herself.

Comment: Paragraph 15 is your almost your third guess and paragraph 9 is your fourth guess.

Comment: Now you've changed the guess it only fits paragraph 9

Comment: @BMS21 paragraph 10, can be fan or stalker?

Comment: @smriti more like a fan

Answer (score 1):

I think the stanzas are referring : (I cant get all of them yet )

> Things related to movie (or professions related to movie)

Obsessive and greedy,
A great desire for some,
Won through hard work,
But can impede on freedom.

> Career in acting

A legend of ancient times,
For the foundations laid he,
A marker for our thinking,
The guide for you and me.

> The Writer

Reach to edge of space,
Beauty and life to meet,
Exceptional to perceivers,
Natural art is such a feat!

> no idea yet

Old British comedy R.I.P,
For one will annoy later,
The surname gives the net,
Now all is stored as data.

> no idea yet

Its seems too many are now,
Some from dance or songs,
The Internet produces a lot,
For many the heart longs.

> umm... choreographer??

To guide from the shadows, 
It’s that which most have sought,
Imagine that it were a job,
For many, they have bought.

> The Producer

Some people have many friends,
Some just hang out as a crew,
Many aspire that become them,
Sometimes that’s me and you.

> co-stars

Suddenly a change of plans,
Will be decided by the chief,
To turn around for best results,
That will be your belief.

> The Director

Often shown as good to us,
Also powerful and buff,
Most will stay unnoticed,
For doing the simple stuff.

> Main Actors

Obsessive they will appear to be,
For loving something dearly,
It could be caused by anything,
From race cars to pepperoni!

> stalker/ fan

Stories are often told to us, 
So ancient from across the seas,
They tell of mighty warriors,
That never asked for fees.

> can be script writer

The next three are grouped as one,
Only differing by their ranking,
To uphold us from the evil ones,
They’re often just out walking.

> no idea yet

Insuring that your transport’s comfy,
They will make your trip better,
It is their job, and they get no praise,
Not even a thank-you letter.

> no idea yet

To use again for faster results,
Taking others working is the key,
Some may view as an evil act,
And expose you for all to see.

> can be paparazzi

They wish to gain power over you,
Most do through promise not fear,
They will change the way you live,
In addition to the rest of the area.

> no idea yet

The latter usually relies on this,
The organise all that they meet,
Through working with every man,
To get only one man his seat.

> no idea yet

Comment: Yeah 10 is fan, but otherwise incorrect sorry